# SQL to group by 2 IDs

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I have a table that's laid out like this:

table1:

```
ID | metric1 | metric2
A  | 1       | 1
A  | 1       | 1
B  | 2       | 3
C  | 3       | 2
```

And another table that may have an alternate ID an item may have (note that the new ID will also be in the table above).  Example:

conversions:

```
old_ID  |  new_ID
A       |  C
```

So I'm trying to create a query that aggregates both on the new ID and the old-ID, but also preserves the old-ID if available.  So basically the results I want look like this:

```
ID  |  potential_old_ID | metric1 | metric2
C   |  A                | 5       | 4
B   |  NULL             | 2       | 3
```

So far with my current strategy I've been able to get close with a query like this:

```
select 
    (CASE WHEN new_ID is null then ID else new_ID END) as ID,
    (CASE WHEN new_ID is null then null else ID END) as potential_old_ID,
    SUM(metric1),
    SUM(metric2)
from table1
left join conversions on ID = old_ID
group by ID, new_ID
```

Which get's me close, but it still separates C and A in separate rows, which doesn't work for my use case:

```
ID  |  potential_old_ID | metric1 | metric2
C   |  A                | 2       | 2
B   |  NULL             | 2       | 3
C   |  NULL             | 3       | 2
```

If I remove the new_ID from the group by I get an error on the query.  Anyway I can get the results I'm looking for that I'm missing?

Comment: Do you ever have an example where D could also have New ID of C?  i.e. the potential old ID could be A,D not just A?

Comment: @DancingFool No everything is 1 to 1 (or 1 to none)

Comment: if anything has more than 2 names you need to write a crazy recursive query, i'd just give up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that the rows that have C already also have the same potential old ID as the ones that are A.  Something like

```
SELECT ID, potential_old_ID, SUM(metric1), SUM(metric2)
FROM
(   select 
        (CASE WHEN c1.new_ID is null then ID else c1.new_ID END) as ID,
        COALESCE(c1.old_ID, c2.old_ID) as potential_old_ID,
        metric1,
        metric2
    from table1
    left join conversions c1 on ID = c1.old_ID
    left join conversions c2 on ID = c2.new_ID
) AS data

GROUP BY ID, potential_old_ID
```

Comment: I tried something like this, can you add the group-by's?  This isn't aggregating the metrics as written.

Comment: Sorry, I was working in an offline editor and pasted the wrong version. Also, alternatively and maybe easier to read, you could do the ID creation in a subquery, then group the results

Comment: I don't believe this query works since new_ID is used in the first column but not included in the group by

Comment: I replaced the query. Sometimes it's easier just to split the group by part from the data manipulation part.

Comment: Still not quite working, one entry has new - new, the other has new - old so they aren't aggregating together.  I think I understand the spirit though let me try something similar.

Comment: I changed your query slightly and it worked.  There's no case I want a new_ID in the second column, was close enough though.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm . . . I think this does what you want:

```
 select coalesce(new_id, id) as id,
        SUM(metric1),
        SUM(metric2)
from table1 left join
     conversions
     on ID = old_ID
group by  coalesce(new_id, id);
```

Comment: The old ID being in the query is important as well